# Can I take out just the username and not the href link?

Tags: regex, vb.net

Today I have a big problem and I have been looking at many different methods over a few hours and none of them are working for me.

I have tried

1. Get Between Functions
2. Regex
3. HTML Agility Pack

The problem is in VB.NET and I want to grab out the title of a film and ignore the html link before it. But the problem is I cant because the link changes for every title, and I do not understand Regex to create the code for it.

Here is the code and the part which says Movie Link 1 is what I want to grab.

```
<a href="/download/fast-and-furious-7-2015-hd-ts-xvid-ac3-hq-hive-cm8-t10472303.html" class="cellMainLink">**Movie Link 1**</a>
```

and of course there is other titles I need to grab too. So the code I got for it is this and it is not working.

```
Dim r As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("class=""cellMainLink"">(?<name>.*)</a>")
    Dim matches As MatchCollection = r.Matches(rssourcecode)


    For Each itemcode As Match In matches
        ListBox1.Items.Add(itemcode.Groups(2).Value)
    Next
```

To anyone who can help me please get back to me as soon as possible.

Thank you.

Comment: [You can't parse HMTL with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: I removed the tags from your title: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 0):

Using [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) you can use this code:

```
Dim links As New List(Of String)()
Dim htmlDoc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(WebSource)
For Each link As HtmlNode In htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class]")
    Dim att As HtmlAttribute = link.Attributes("class")
    If att.Value = "cellMainLink" Then
        links.Add(link.Value)
    End If
Next
```

I do not believe you need a regex solution here. However, just for the educational purpose:

```
Dim ptrn As String = "<a\b[^>]*?class=[""']?cellMainLink[""']?[^>]*?>(.*?)</a>"
Dim input As String = "<a href=""/download/fast-and-furious-7-2015-hd-ts-xvid-ac3-hq-hive-cm8-t10472303.html"" class=""cellMainLink"">**Movie Link 1**</a>"
Dim dds As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
Dim rx As Regex = New Regex(ptrn)
Dim result As String = rx.Match(input).Groups(1).Value
```

Result: `**Movie Link 1**`

Comment: I was looking at  your HTML Agility pack code but I dont know how implement that into my code.

Comment: What about regex? If your `<a>` tag value spans across multiple lines, you can add `(?s)` inline option: `Dim ptrn As String = "(?s)<a\b[^>]*?class=[""']?cellMainLink[""']?[^>]*?>(.*?)</a>"`.

Comment: Either I am wrong with the way im getting this data or you are misunderstood. Sorry dont mean to sound rude but just saying I dont have a clue how to implement that code

Comment: Do you mean to say you do not know how to use a `Regex` object? Just add `Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions` at the top of the file. For Agility Pack, you need to install it as a NuGet package (right click the solution name and select Manage NuGetPackages, then search for it, and install. See http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I know how to install regex and Agility Pack but when I use a web client to download the site and regex to scrape the code it doesn't work.

Comment: Please use http://pastebin.com/ to share the contents you are parsing, and I will try to provide a working solution.

Comment: I am sorry, we have a public holiday, I am busy with family matters right now, I will check once I have spare minute.

Comment: You can add the links extracted this way: `ListBox1.Items.Add(itemcode.Groups(1).Value)`. I do not know what you want to do with `Split`, but if you want to add String[] elements to a listbox, you need to use `AddRange()` method: `ListBox1.Items.AddRange(itemcode.Groups(1).Value.Split(""))`. However, this will just print the former value.